# Does an element of a Cartesian product necessarily belong to a set containing that product?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

Let $X=\{A,\{c,d\}^2\}$ be a set. Then,
\begin{gather}
\{c,d\}^2=\{c,d\}\times\{c,d\}=\{(c,c),(c,d),(d,c),(d,d)\}
\end{gather}

My question is: does the pair $(c,d)$ belong to the set $X$? In other words, **does an element of a Cartesian product belong to a set containing that product?**

The motivation here is to better understand the property of what it means to be an element of a set and to learn more about the connection between a cartesian product and the elements of the set generated by the cartesian product of two valid sets.

Comment: $\{c,d\}$ is not a pair (unless $c,d$ are special). If you want to go the braces way you'll have to write the actual Kuratowski pairs $$\{c,d\}\times\{c,d\}=\{\{\{c\}\}, \{\{c\},\{c,d\}\}, \{\{d\},\{d,c\}\}, \{\{d\}\}\}$$ Or use standard notations such as $(,)$ or $\langle,\rangle$.

Comment: Thank you. Is the question answerable after the edits?

Comment: Yes, it is, and the answer is: not unless $A$ is one of the elements of $\{c,d\}^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your set $X=\{A,\{c,d\}^2\}$, there are two elements. $A$ and $\{c,d\}^2$. Therefore, your question of whether or not the pair $(c,d)$ is an element of $X$ depends on how we define the set $A$.

If $A = (c,d)$, then because $A$ is an element of $X$, we know that $(c,d)$ is an element of $X$. However, if $A$ is defined to be anything else, then the answer is no, $(c,d)$ is not an element of $X$.

---

*More generally, $A$ is an element of $\{A\}$, but is not an element of $\{\{A\}\}$. The only element of $\{\{A\}\}$ is $\{A\}$ (which is not equal to $A$).*